# A for loop within a for loop that is split

Tags: templating, forloop, loop

Possibly a bad question title...sorry but wasn't sure how to describe it.

Basically I have a for loop that every 4 items I want to pull in a different item from another loop. This is a series of Q&A's in a staff interview, and each 4th item I want to break the side by side and pull in a full width quote.

Here is the breakdown of the code.

```
{% set pullQuotes =
  [
    'My biggest source of pride to date is my involvement in the Olympic Park Project: that’s part of my personal legacy.',
    'Frosts is a family environment. We’re successful from within. With our recent management acquisition of Frosts Landscapes, we’ve developed a new atmosphere, new business, and a great environment to work in. '
  ] %}

  <ul class="lg:flex lg:flex-wrap lg:justify-around">
    {% for row in entry.questionsAndAnswers %}
      {#            {% set width = loop.index is divisible by(3) ? 'lg:w-full' : 'lg:w-1/2' %}#}
      <li class="lg:w-1/2 py-6 px-6 max-w-xl">
        <h3 class="font-black text-18 mb-3">{{ row.question }}</h3>
        <div class="italic mb-12">
          {{ row.answer }}
        </div>
      </li>

      {% if loop.index % 4 == 0 and not loop.last %}

        {% for entry in pullQuotes %}
          <li class="w-full flex justify-center mb-12">
            <div>
              {{ svg('@icons/quote.svg', class="w-20 h-20  text-lime-500 flex-shrink-0 fill-current") }}
            </div>
            <blockquote class="pl-3 py-3 max-w-xl text-20 text-semibold text-lime-500 italic">
              {{ entry }}
            </blockquote>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
      {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
  </ul>
```

The problem I have is that the loop of the pullQuotes is being iterated each time after every 4th item. What I want to do is pull the first item from the pull Quotes in position 4 and the second item from pullQuotes in position 8 and so on...

Both of these will be CMS managed and so the number of Q&A's and pullQuotes could vary, so it needs to be flexible.

Anyone able to help me figure this one out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this; you get the pull quote index by dividing the loop index by 4 (will always return an int) and then you modulo that index against the length of your quotes array:

```
{% if loop.index % 4 == 0 and not loop.last %}
      {% set entry = pullQuotes[(loop.index / 4) % (pullQuotes | length) - 1] %}
      <li class="w-full flex justify-center mb-12">
        <div>
          {{ svg('@icons/quote.svg', class="w-20 h-20  text-lime-500 flex-shrink-0 fill-current") }}
        </div>
        <blockquote class="pl-3 py-3 max-w-xl text-20 text-semibold text-lime-500 italic">
          {{ entry }}
        </blockquote>
      </li>
{% endif %}
```

Comment: That's nice @Seb, only issue is the pullQuotes are in reverse order with this code.

Comment: @TerryUpton ah yes because of the 0 indexing, corrected the answer now.

Comment: I believe changing the {% set entry = pullQuotes[(loop.index / 4) % (pullQuotes | length) - 1] %} to {% set entry = pullQuotes[(loop.index0 / 4) % (pullQuotes | length) - 1] %}